# How to write proper test for reactive interface repository which returns Observable only when there is some event, how to mock triggering that event

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to write proper test for my reactive repository, which just listen for location changes. I don't want to actually listen for location changes and just 'invoke' new location change multiple times with just created custom Location.

Here is the repository and its function for gathering locations:

```
interface RxLocationRepository {

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun onLocationUpdate(): Observable<Location>

fun stopLocationUpdates()
}
```

Here is the implementation of it, which actually DON'T MATTER because i don't want to listen for real location updates, but i want to show you that it is just reactive implementation for listen to LocationManager updates:

```
class LocationNativeRepository(
    val locationManager: LocationManager,
    val geoEventsDistanceMeters: Int,
    val geoEventsIntervalSeconds: Int) : RxLocationRepository{

var locationToPopulate: Location = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
lateinit var mLocationCallbackNativeApi: LocationListener
private val subject: BehaviorSubject<Location> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(locationToPopulate)
var locationEmitter: Observable<Location> = subject.hide()

init {
    configureNativeLocationEmitter()
}

override fun onLocationUpdate(): Observable<Location> {
    return locationEmitter
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationCallbackNativeApi)
}


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun configureNativeLocationEmitter() {

    mLocationCallbackNativeApi = object : LocationListener {

        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            subject.onNext(location)
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}

    }

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                (geoEventsIntervalSeconds * 1000).toLong(),
                geoEventsDistanceMeters.toFloat(),
                mLocationCallbackNativeApi,
                Looper.getMainLooper())
    } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
        ignored.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                (geoEventsIntervalSeconds * 1000).toLong(),
                geoEventsDistanceMeters.toFloat(),
                mLocationCallbackNativeApi,
                Looper.getMainLooper())
    } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
        ignored.printStackTrace()
    }
 }

}
```

So how i can invoke this repository in my test to actually trigger the onLocationUpdate() method? So for example i will make it emit 3 times location like this:

```
 val location = Location("test").apply {
        latitude = 1.234
        longitude = 5.678
        accuracy = 20f
        time = Date().time
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `PublishSubject<Location>` variable. Create an anonymous sub-class of `RxLocationRepository`, where the `onLocationUpdate()` method returns the variable. Then emit values into the variable to provide new locations.